# How to make the code work with other tags and add class to it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the following code to automatically copy selected text:

```
function copy(elem){
    if($(elem).text()){
        var dummy = document.createElement("textarea");
        document.body.appendChild(dummy);
        dummy.value = $(elem).text();
        dummy.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(dummy);
    }else{
        input  = $(elem).val();
        elem.select();//Select the text in the input element 
        document.execCommand('copy');//copy it 
    }



    $(elem).next().text('discount code has been copied);
    setTimeout(function(){$(elem).next().text('');}, 2000);//
}
```

`

I have two questions regarding that code:

1. If I want to use it in my post, I'm adding this code: `<p class="kod-rabatowy" onclick="copy(this)">example text that needs to be copied</p>` in text editor. The thing is that the whole script only works with `<p>` tags - I really need to display the text in the same line. How can I make it work with other tags as well (`<b>` would be perfect)?

   2. How can I add class to the whole script so I could style the text saying that the code has been copied? Here you can see how it works now: http://test2.gromocje.pl/?p=21 (click on "test" button and you'll copy it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's working fine with  (I don't know about Wordpress posts): https://jsbin.com/yoropunebu/edit?html,css,js,output

I also added the class thing you wanted:

```
    $(elem).next().addClass("copied-response").text('discount code has been copied');
```

Comment: Thank you! The class works great :) However when the popup fades away, it leaves a small inperfection - https://screenshots.firefox.com/RxUq59Tx7kCP8GDr/test2.gromocje.pl - do you have any idea how to get rid of it? It happened when I added padding to the style.

As for the issue with p tags, I don't know why, but still only p works. What can be the reason?

Comment: It leaves the imperfection because the you don't delete or hide the element, you just empty it's content. You should try hiding it {display: none}

Comment: Forgot to do this, sorry. Thank you!